# Editable Inline Email Template

Tags: email, mailchimp

How can I create an email template and send to someone and then the person can make edits right in their email account?
Is there a way I can do this with mailchimp or there is another service for it?

Answer (score 0):

Used my browser's developer tools to inspect element and made my edits

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mailchimp's mc:edit feature!

Mark any element with a unique `mc:edit="identifier"` and that area becomes editable under the DESIGN tab in the templates area in your MC account.